# make image into a circle

Tags: css, wordpress

I have images in a slideshow on [this page](http://testsitemg.com/meor-yale/shabbat). I would like the square images to become circluar using css. 
I am having a hard time using inspect element b/c the images are in a slideshow. Which class can I use to add border-radius to make the square image eg of the pasta salad/potatoes into a circle shape?

```
<div id="rev_slider_22_3_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container" style="margin:0px auto;background-color:#E9E9E9;padding:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;max-height:400px;">
    <div id="rev_slider_22_3" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" style="display:none;max-height:400px;height:400px;">
<ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->
    <li data-transition="fade,boxfade,slotfade-horizontal,slotfade-vertical,fadetoleftfadefromright,fadetorightfadefromleft,fadetotopfadefrombottom,fadetobottomfadefromtop" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300"  data-saveperformance="off" >
        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
        <img src="http://xxx.image.jpg"  alt="challah-1"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
        <!-- LAYERS -->
    </li>
    <!-- SLIDE  -->
    <li data-transition="fade,boxfade,slotfade-horizontal,slotfade-vertical,fadetoleftfadefromright,fadetorightfadefromleft,fadetotopfadefrombottom,fadetobottomfadefromtop" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300"  data-saveperformance="off" >
        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
        <img src="http://xxx/meatballs.jpg"  alt="matza-balls"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
        <!-- LAYERS -->
    </li>
    <!-- SLIDE  -->
```

Comment: _“I am having a hard time using inspect element b/c the images are in a slideshow”_ – well then make the slideshow not start automatically, or set the timer between slides to a really high value … then there should be nothing more standing in the way of inspecting elements for as long as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.tp-simpleresponsive >ul li {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.rev_slider_wrapper {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply border radius 50% to your square image to make it circular.

```
.circular-image {
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While the best way to accomplish this is to use:

```
.circular-image {
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You need to be aware that in most cases, you need to apply a min-width, and min-height or else your result may not be as expected in some brosers/uses.